# no pdcures.dll created when using make -f Makefile for win 10 pdcurses

Tags: windows, ncurses, pdcurses

I have been trying to install PDcurses on my Windows 10 machine. The README.md says to run: `make -f Makefile` to build pdcures.dll in the 'wincon' folder. However when i ran this in Powershell it did not create any .dll, instead creating many .o files.

Then i tried to run 'make -f Makefile.wcc' in Powershell and it returned the error 'makefile.wcc:9: *** missing separator. Stop.' I got similar errors using Makefile.bcc and Makefile.vc.
What am i doing wrong here? Am i supposed to build one of the .c files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the Makefiles is compiler-specific, as described in the [README.md](https://pdcurses.org/wincon/). There's no reason to try Makefiles intended for compilers other than the one you're using.

The Makefile doesn't build a DLL, by default -- only a static library (ending in .a or .lib). PDCurses is a small library, and there's not much benefit in building it as a DLL. But if you want to, that procedure is also described in the README.md. In short:

```
make DLL=Y
```

but please read the file for details. Note that, even if you build PDCurses as a DLL, you'll still *also* need the .a or .lib file to link against.